Can an unconfirmed transaction be confirmed several years later?
Suppose that I make a transaction, but due to a low fee it is not confirmed even after several weeks. The transaction is then removed from the mempool of most nodes (and also my wallet disregards the transaction and allows to spend the coins again).
But since the transaction was signed and publicly broadcast to the network (all nodes), is it possible that anyone can rebroadcast the transaction and the transaction can eventually be confirmed even years later, if I do not spend the coins used in the transaction in the meantime?

Yes, that is possible. If the UTXOs still exist and the transaction is otherwise valid, then it could still be confirmed after all of that time.
